# How to generalize the code of a file upload web form for multiple forms with different id attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I have the following web form to upload a single file using jquery, showing a progress bar and displaying a message when the file has been uploaded:

```
 <form id="uploadFileForm" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="file" size="60" name="fileToUpload" />
         <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
     <div id="progress">
            <div id="bar"></div>
            <div id="percent">0%</div >
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="message"></div>
```

In the head section of the webpage I have the related javascript code that detects the upload form through its id, along with the css that formats the progress bar and message divs:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var options = { 
        beforeSend: function() 
        {
            $("#progress").show();
            //clear everything
            $("#bar").width(\'0%\');
            $("#message").html("");
            $("#percent").html("0%");
        },
        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) 
        {
            $("#bar").width(percentComplete+\'%\');
            $("#percent").html(percentComplete+\'%\');
        },
        success: function() 
        {
            $("#bar").width(\'100%\');
            $("#percent").html(\'100%\');

        },
        complete: function(response) 
        {
            $("#message").html("<font color=\'#85a129\'>"+response.responseText+"</font>");
        },
        error: function()
        {
            $("#message").html("<font color=\'#CC3300\'> ERROR: unable to upload files</font>");
        }

    }; 
         $("#uploadFileForm").ajaxForm(options);
    });

    </script>

    <style>
    #progress { position:relative; width:400px; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 1px; border-radius: 3px; }
    #bar { background-color: #85a129; width:0%; height:20px; border-radius: 3px; }
    #percent { position:absolute; display:inline-block; top:3px; left:48%; }
    </style>
```

Everything works perfectly and I'm happy with it. However I would like to have multiple forms in separate areas of the same page that allow the upload of other files (one form per file). I achieved this by adding new forms and by duplicating the javascript code for each one of the forms changing the ids (e.g. uploadFileForm2, uploadFileForm3,...) along with the ids of the divs associated to the progress bars (progress2,bar2,percent2,...) and messages (message2,...).

This is obviosly very redundant.

How can I generalize my javascript code so that it detects all the ids of the upload forms  along with their respective progress bars and messages?

Is there also a way to have a single css specification for all the progress bars even if they have different ids?

Comment: whether the same dom structure is maintained every where like the `progress2` follows the form and `message` after progress

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
//Add data-progress and data-message with the id of those as values
<form id="uploadFileForm" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-progress="#progress" data-message="#message">
    <input type="file" size="60" name="fileToUpload" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
<div id="progress" class="progress">
    <div id="bar" class="bar"></div>
    <div id="percent" class="percent">0%</div>
</div>
<br />
<div id="message" class="message"></div>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function ajaxSubmit(form) {
        var $form = $(form),
            $progress = $($form.data('progress')),
            $message = $($form.data('message')),
            $bar = $progress.find(".bar"),
            $percent = $progress.find(".percent");
        var options = {
            beforeSend: function () {
                $progress.show();
                //clear everything
                $bar.width('0%');
                $percent.html("");
                $message.html("0%");
            },
            uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                $bar.width(percentComplete + '%');
                $percent.html(percentComplete + '%');
            },
            success: function () {
                $bar.width('100%');
                $progress.find(".percent").html('100%');

            },
            complete: function (response) {
                $message.html("<font color=\'#85a129\'>" + response.responseText + "</font>");
            },
            error: function () {
                $message.html("<font color=\'#CC3300\'> ERROR: unable to upload files</font>");
            }

        };
    }
    ajaxSubmit($("#uploadFileForm"));
    ajaxSubmit($("#uploadFileForm1"));
    ajaxSubmit($("#uploadFileForm2"));
});
```